# nested parallel process in R - Using ParSapply inside a Foreach loop

Tags: r, parallel-processing, parallel-foreach, doparallel

I am using doParallel package and want to use `parSapply ()` inside a `Foreach loop` but I am not sure how can I use a parallel function inside the other parallel loop.

I have got this error :

```
Error in { : task 1 failed - "could not find function "parSapply""
Called from: e$fun(obj, substitute(ex), parent.frame(), e$data)
```

Comment: can you provide sample code, so it is possible to reproduce your error?
usually this error is caused because you don't load your library in the foreach loop. You can look that up in the foreach documentation.

Comment: Why do you want to parallelize inside a parallel function? It sounds like a poor use of threading and waste of overhead to me.